# Pass an Array as a parameter does not work

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using DataTables.js and want to pass an array as a parameter:

**This piece of code works (see columnDefs):**

```
    var table = $('#html_table').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "e.g.: .msg, AU2019-00XX",
            search: "Filter Results"
        },
        order: [
            [response.order_by_column, response.order_by]
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            { width: 70, targets: 0 }, { width: 50, targets: 1 }, { width: 50, targets: 2 },
            {otherStuff...},
            {otherStuff...}
        ]
```

**But this piece of code does not work (see columnDefs):**

Array Creation

```
    html_col_width = []
    for(i=0; i<response.html_col_width.length; i++){
        html_col_width.push({
            "width": response.html_col_width[i],
            "targets": i
        })
    }
```

Data Table Creation

```
    var table = $('#html_table').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "e.g.: .msg, AU2019-00XX",
            search: "Filter Results"
        },
        order: [
            [response.order_by_column, response.order_by]
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            html_col_width,
            {otherStuff...},
            {otherStuff...}
        ]
```

Why is it not possible to pass "html_col_width" as a parameter?

Comment: `columnDefs: [ html_col_width ]` -> `columnDefs: html_col_width`

Comment: Thank you, but no, does not work. I am passing some other variables in columnDefs as well. (And it works with "[ ]" in the one which works.

Comment: In the one that works you have an array that contains objects. The `html_col_width` variable is also an array that contains objects. By doing `[ html_col_width ]` you're making an array which contains an array which contains objects. Therefore, the correct format is to *not* wrap another array around `html_col_width`. If that doesn't work, then there is another problem that I cannot identify. What *is* the issue you get? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I edited my post, where you can see why I can not remove the square brackets. Maybe my answer is now more clear. .. "{otherStuff...}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each element of the `html_col_width` array should be a separate element of the `columnDefs` array, you can use spread syntax to merge it into the array:

```
columnDefs: [
    ... html_col_width,
    { otherstuff...},
    { otherstuff...}
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try tomorrow and respond!